# Mark key positions on a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with its own scrollbar using the `overflow: auto` property.
With this `div` I display a table. For some of the rows I would like to display markers on the scrollbar of their positions within the `div`.

At the moment I am calculating the position of the desired rows I want to mark within the scrollbar by subtracting the offsets from the parent `div`, and then I am creating div with their fixed position

With the newly created `div`, how do I display that position on the scrollbar rather then in the div or is it even possible to add fixed divs on the scrollbar?

Comment: You might want to show us some of your code.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no good way to do this. The scrollbar created by `overflow: auto` is a bit of a weird beast: its size and metrics are dependent on the browser and OS, and cannot be reliably detected by Javascript.

(For example, the scrollbar on most Windows systems will have "buttons" at the top and bottom, but the Mac OS scrollbar does not; this changes the positioning of the scroll thumb for content, as it affects the overall length of the scrollbar. In fact, the Mac OS scrollbar is invisible by default on many systems, so attempting to position content over it will look rather strange!)

About the only way I can imagine going about this would be to forego the native scrollbar entirely and use a Javascript-created standin, but those tend to have wonky behavior that will piss users off. Unless this feature is *extremely* important to you, I'd be inclined to write it off as impossible.